# Websocket connection dropping in Safari when page not in focus in iOS 15

Tags: javascript, websocket

Our website use web-socket and the web-socket connection drop randomly when the page not in focus for a while. but the web socket state is till show "OPEN". this is occurred in safari in iOS15.

this issue is occurred very randomly.

Comment: Is the ```close``` event triggered when this issue occurs? If yes, can't you just reconnect? If not, how do you notice the connection is dead?

Comment: @flappix thanks for you response. We add a setTimeout event for 60 seconds when each message send out from client to our server. We will throw an timeout error out when we not receive response for a message after 60 seconds. about 1% of visitor got this timeout error and both from iOS15 safari.

Comment: @flappix I can make sure now. The onClose event is not triggered, onError event is not triggered as well. state code is 1. this only happened in our live site randomly, we track this by Sentry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for this. You could try to just establish a new connection when you notice you don't get a response message. You can also try to use a wrapper library like socket.io which has already some mechanisms built-in to improve connection stability and reliability.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.